# Symbol not found objc class reference

Tags: objective-c

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_InputAmountVC", referenced from:

objc-class-ref-to-InputAmountVC in p0931917_prac_2AppDelegate.o

ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Ld "build/Debug-iphonesimulator/p0931917 prac 2.app/p0931917 prac 2" normal i386
cd "/Volumes/Storage/p0931917 prac 2"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk "-L/Volumes/Storage/p0931917 prac 2/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-F/Volumes/Storage/p0931917 prac 2/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" -filelist "/Volumes/Storage/p0931917 prac 2/build/p0931917 prac 2.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/p0931917 prac 2.build/Objects-normal/i386/p0931917 prac 2.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -o "/Volumes/Storage/p0931917 prac 2/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/p0931917 prac 2.app/p0931917 prac 2"

dyld: shared cached file was build against a different libSystem.dylib, ignoring cache
dyld: shared cached file was build against a different libSystem.dylib, ignoring cache
dyld: shared cached file was build against a different libSystem.dylib, ignoring cache
dyld: shared cached file was build against a different libSystem.dylib, ignoring cache
dyld: shared cached file was build against a different libSystem.dylib, ignoring cache
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_InputAmountVC", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-InputAmountVC in p0931917_prac_2AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm having this error please help.

Answer (score 1):

The linker doesn't find the object code (binary) for that particular class.

If it is your code, make sure to have the .m/.mm/.c/.cpp source file belong to the target you are building.

If it is in a library, make sure the linker can find it (library search path etc.) and was actually build with the same settings.

The latter paragraph about *dyld* looks like your problem is just that: dyld was build against another version of libSystem.dylib than your current target, so basically it doesn't have the code you need in it. (Other architecture or base SDK?)